# Ngx-Chips - Autocomplete list not updated after receiving response

Tags: angular, list, ngx-chips

I am using [ngx-chips](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/) plugin in my project.

Now the dropdown list is populated using Http call to server.

`myContactList` data is updated on view as well but I cannot see the dropdown. If I type some text again the list shows up. But the list is old one not the data of latest request.

These is also one issue registered in this plugin. [See issue here](https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/issues/375)

I want list to update and show up as I receive response pron server.

HTML :

```
<tag-input id="myAnchor"  [(ngModel)]='items' (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event)" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true">
    <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="myContactList">
        <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
            {{ item.display }}
            <delete-icon (click)="input.removeItem(item, index)"></delete-icon>
        </ng-template>
    </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>   

{{myContactList | json}}
```

TS :

```
onTextChange(text) {
    const data = {'Text': text};
    this.Service = this.myContactService.getSearchedContacts(data).subscribe(responseData => {
        this.myContactList = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < responseData.length; index++) {
            responseData[index].display = responseData[index].name;
            responseData[index].value = responseData[index].id;
            this.myContactList.push(responseData[index]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The same problem :)

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me like this:

```
<tag-input   [(ngModel)]='items' (onTextChange)="change($event)" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="false">
<tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [autocompleteItems]="preparedTags">
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
    {{ item.display }}
    <delete-icon (click)="input.removeItem(item, index)"></delete-icon>
  </ng-template>
</tag-input-dropdown>
```

```
 change(value) {
this.preparedTags = [];
this.zone.run(() => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.apiProvider.getSimpleSearchKeyWords(value)
      .then((res) => {


          for (let i = 0; i < JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).data.length; i++) {

          this.preparedTags.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).data[i].type + " " + JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).data[i].text)

          }
        }, (err) => {

        }
      );

  }, 100);

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reference code bellow:
HTML:

```
<tag-input name='tag2' [ngClass]="'tag-select'" theme='bootstrap'  
                                        [placeholder]="'Select Name +'" [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Select Name +'"
                                        [ngModel]="['Material']" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"  (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event)" (onSelect)="onSelectedre($event)" (onAdd)="onItemAddeder($event)"[editable]='true' (onTagEdited)="onTagEdited($event)">
                                        <tag-input-dropdown [appendToBody]="false" [displayBy]="'Name'" [identifyBy]="'id'"
                                          [autocompleteObservable]="requestAutocompleteItems "  (onAdd)="onItemAdded($event)"
                                          (onSelect)="onSelectedtag($event)" >
 </tag-input-dropdown>
 </tag-input>
```

.ts file:

```
 lstCallAPI=['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

        loadPropertyTypeData(){
        this._dataService.get('/api/product/get-add-property')
        .subscribe((response: any) => {
         for (let index = 0; index < response.result.length; index++) {
           const element = response.result[index];
          this.lstCallAPI.push(element.Name);
         }
          this.modalOverflow.show();
        });
      }
    public requestAutocompleteItems = (text: string): Observable<string[]> => {
      return of(this.lstCallAPI);
    };
```